# Can I change the color of the last few letters of a text string in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, t-sql

I have an issue with a web application that I am developing. This condists of a standard list view with sql scripts to return the data which is bound to the listview. I have appended a string to the end of one of the columns like so;

```
CASE WHEN COLUMN1 DATE > 10/19/15 THEN COLUMN1 + 'NEW' ELSE COLUMN1.
```

Is it possible to change the color of the 'NEW' string as it appears on the page in SQL by passing styles or html to the web page for example.

I ask this as I cannot use c# or JS due to a number of reasons...

Has anybody done something similar in T-SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: SQL is not concerned with the presentation of data. And if you are able to change the appearance of text by inserting HTML into your database then you have a XSS vulnerability because you're not correctly HTML-encoding your output.

Comment: Why can't you use some code in your pages' render logic to alter the appearance of the text?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response...I am not storing any html, I just thought It may be able to output some to a webpage much like you can arrange html tables for emails using SQL...I have also attempted to hook into the ondatabound property of the list view. However, once I have substringed the text property of my link buttons I am struggling to re-apply the 'NEW' substring to the text property...

Comment: Please post your code where you render data to the user. You implied you're using ASP.NET's data-binding features, so please provide as much code as possible (code-behind, `*.aspx` markup, and final rendered HTML markup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the old length of the text in a separate column and later use this information in order to split the text in two parts and display them using different colors.

This has the advantage, that you can keep your text pure, i.e. without any formattings or separators. You also don't have any formatting logic on the DB side.